# re.pl: Variable cannot be used in print, but seems to keep reference, what happens

Tags: perl, read-eval-print-loop

Using `re.pl` from Devel::REPL:

```
eddie@MYPC0:~$ re.pl
$ $a++
0
$ $a++
1
$ $a++
2
$ $a++
3
$ $a++
4
$ $a++
5
$ $a++
6
$ print $a
1
$ $a++
7
```

`print $a` prints `1` whether I initialize the variable or not. It seems it cannot `print $a` and it prints another sort of reference, also I don't understand if it loses the reference why is the value printed `1` instead of `0`

Another test:

```
eddie@MYPC0:~$ re.pl
$ $a =1
1
$ print $a
1
$ $a++
1
$ print $a
1
$ $a++
2
$ $a++
3
$ print $a
1
$ $a++
4
$ print $a
1
$ $a++
5
$ $a
6
$ print $a
1
```

And yet another

```
eddie@MYPC0:~$ re.pl
$ my $a=0
0
$ print $a
1
$
$ $a
0
$
```

Comment: What's `re.pl`?

Comment: @Dada `re.pl` ( read-eval-print-loop - Perl interactive shell)

Comment: I see question is flagged with need debugging details, what other details, I put all the input values on a clean iteractive Perl, there are no other details, who voted please give details what exactly should I post,

Comment: 1) Perl doesn't have a builtin `re.pl` program, and the closest to a builtin REPL it has is `perl -de1` (and it's not what you're running). 2) it looks like you actually mean `re.pl` from `Devel::REPL` (it should have been included in your question). 3) I can't reproduce. 4) it looks like the `1` is the return value from `print $a` rather than what actually got printed. Once again, hard to help you without more details.

Comment: Re "*Needs debugging details*", Fixed it for you. Let me know if it gets closed, and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Dada, Re "*I can't reproduce*", Install Term::Readline::Gnu. `re.pl` works a lot better with it, but it introduces this particularity.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Term::ReadLine::Gnu, @ikegami. Another missing piece of information to the question is "how did you exit re.pl?". Personally, I use Ctrl-D, which prints the buferred `print` outputs before exiting. It looks like using instead Ctrl-C does reproduce the issue, but this is the kind of details that should have been in the question. Although I agree that it doesn't matter now, OP has accepted the answer, and even with the lack of details, it's answerable; just not a very detailed question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

re.pl is showing you the *return value of `print`*. The `print` builtin "returns true" (i.e. `1`) if it was able to successfully print something.

```
andrew@goron:~$ re.pl
$ $a = 42;
42
$ print $a;
1
$ print 0;
1
$ print "banana";
1
```

The reason you don't see any output from `print` itself is because Devel::REPL buffers output until it gets a newline:

```
andrew@goron:~$ re.pl
$ print "Hello";
1
$ print ", World!\n";
Hello, World!
1
```

Comment: So if I want to use print I should do `print "$a\n"`

Comment: Or `use feature 'say'` and then `say $a`

Comment: Indeed `print "$a\n"` but I have to use it everytime with a trailing `\n` otherwise it will print all the prints before

Comment: @user20284150 yes, but the answer is very useful because I understand now why print didn't work and how to make it work...

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu generally I'd say don't use `print` directly in re.pl. If you call some code that uses `print` indirectly, fine, but if you want to see the value of something in the repl, just skip the `print`. Likewise use `sprintf` rather than `printf`.

Comment: Re "*but I have to use it everytime with a trailing `\n`*", No, you can use `say $a;` as previously mentioned, or better yet just `$a`.

Comment: @ikegami yes but sometimes, I learn Perl, I need to test my print so I need to use `print` in interactive mode to learn all the usecases, and for this the current answer that details the peculiar behaviour in `re.pl` is pretty useful

Comment: @Eduard Florinescu It's not peculiar to `re.pl`. All Perl (and C and C++ and ...) programs behave this way by default.

Comment: @ikegami I think I remember from school something now that you say, python's `print` made me forget all these details, good remider,

Comment: @Eduard Florinescu, Python is the same too. If you don't print a LF, you get the same results. But Python's `print` prints a LF by default. Perl's equivalent, as already mentioned, is `say` . `say` is identical `print` except that it also prints a LF.